# Rename folder in the directory and its subdirectories using shell script?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell

I hava many folder named "XXXXX"， just rename it to "OOOO", how to write the script?

Comment: You don't need a script. See: [man rename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your folder are nested use `find` command with an attached `remane` command, like this:

```
find /path/to/your/folder -depth -iname XXXX -execdir rename s/XXXX/OOOO/ {} \;
```

Otherwise, just use `rename`:

```
 rename s/XXXX/OOOO/
```

Comment: Did you test this, after the first rename in shallowest directory any sub-directories won't be renamed as `.../XXXX/XXXX` is now `.../OOOO/XXXX`.

Comment: You were right, sudo_O, it failed on subdirectories. I've added `-depth` switch to correct it.